# How to uninstall virtualbox package: "is not installed, so not removed"

Tags: apt, virtualbox, dpkg

I'm trying to remove virtualbox from pc but I can't remove package.

dpkg can sees it:

```
dpkg -l 'virtualbox*' | grep ^i
in  virtualbox-5.0           <none>       amd64        (no description available)
```

but when I try to remove:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-5.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'virtualbox-5.0' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

sudo apt autoremove --purge virtualbox-5.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'virtualbox-5.0' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How can I remove this package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dpkg -l` shows that the package is not installed `in`.

The first character in `in` means that the package is marked for installation, the second means that it is not currently installed.

Comment: how can I remove it? When I run virtualbox in terminal I get: bash: /usr/bin/virtualbox: No such file or directory

Comment: It is already removed.